# How to Specify MOTO (Mail Order Telephone Order) for Stripe/PHP?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am struggling to figure out how to specify a MOTO payment with Stripe API and PHP. I believe I specify MOTO in the `payment_method_options` on the confirm (javascript), and I have to specify confirm = true in the create (PHP). I am struggling to get the example from [here](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/tree/master/using-webhooks/server/php/public) to work with MOTO although it works fine without.

**script.js** (I add `payment_method_options: { card: {moto:true} }`) to `confirmCardPayment`...

```
var pay = function(stripe, card, clientSecret) {
    changeLoadingState(true);

    // Initiate the payment.
    // If authentication is required, confirmCardPayment will automatically display a modal
    stripe
        .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, { payment_method: { card: card }, payment_method_options: { card: {moto:true} } })
        .then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Show error to your customer
                showError(result.error.message);
            } else {
                // The payment has been processed!
                orderComplete(clientSecret);
            }
        });
};
```

**confirm-intent.php** I specify confirm=true and include `payment_method` in the output...

```
use Stripe\PaymentIntent;
use Stripe\Stripe;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$paymentIntent = PaymentIntent::create([
   'amount' => 2000,
   'currency' => 'gbp',
   'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
   'confirm' => true
]);

$output = [
    'publishableKey' => 'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
    'payment_method' => $paymentIntent->id,
];

echo json_encode($output);
```

The error I am currently getting is...

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_1D9UTDO2IIp8zI) You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method. You can either update the PaymentIntent with a payment method and then confirm it again, or confirm it again directly with a payment method.

The payment method is the id of the payment intent, I think. I have put it into the output of the payment intent script but this does not work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're confused about what a PaymentIntent is and what a PaymentMethod is(`'payment_method' => $paymentIntent->id`, makes no sense to me). In any case, you simply need to remove `'confirm' => true` from that PHP code I believe— you can't confirm the PaymentIntent without supplying a PaymentMethod, and the PaymentMethod is not supplied until the frontend calls confirmCardPayment (which takes the card information currently inside of the CardElement form input, creates a PaymentMethod, and confirms the PaymentIntent with it(i.e. charges that card))

Comment: Also your use case confuses me a little, because a MOTO payment implies that the payment happens without the customer directly entering their card information on your web page, but you're using Elements and stripe.js which implies that the customer _is_ entering that information, so you wouldn't need MOTO. Maybe Stripe's support can help!

Comment: I do need MOTO, if you imagine it's like a call center. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform a MOTO stripe payment, there are requirements as follows:

1. You need to activate the MOTO payment option with stripe directly.
2. You need to perform a single payment action, which is a paymentIntent with confirm=true. Making a paymentIntent first with confirmCardPayment later won't work in this case.

The paymentIntent action in this case would look like this: (the following is a curl request, you can convert it to your backend language)

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
  -u sk_test_NfCI7U9wkvqjrgJRFirEuwjN \
  -d amount=1099 \
  -d currency=eur \
  -d "payment_method_data[type]"=card \
  -d "payment_method_data[card][number]"=4242424242424242 \
  -d "payment_method_data[card][exp_month]"=4 \
  -d "payment_method_data[card][exp_year]"=24 \
  -d "payment_method_data[card][cvc]"=242 \
  -d "payment_method_options[card][moto]"=true \
  -d confirm=true
```

It will return either an error or a successful payment result, which you can use for your further actions.

Alternatively you can first create the paymentMethod and then make a confirmed intent with paymentMethod ID (to avoid sending card details directly and to make use of stripe card input UI elements). See more about how to create a payment method first here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously#create-a-paymentmethod

If you do it, your MOTO API call would look like this:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
  -u sk_test_NfCI7U9wkvqjrgJRFirEuwjN \
  -d amount=1099 \
  -d currency=eur \
  -d "payment_method"=<YOUR paymentMethodID> \
  -d "payment_method_options[card][moto]"=true \
  -d confirm=true
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved using

```
var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents";
var httpRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer sk_test_YOURKEY...";

var data = "amount=1099&currency=eur&payment_method_data[type]=card&payment_method_data[card][number]=4242424242424242&payment_method_data[card][exp_month]=4&payment_method_data[card][exp_year]=24&payment_method_data[card][cvc]=242&payment_method_options[card][moto]=true&confirm=true";

using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream())){streamWriter.Write(data);}
var httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();}
Response.Write("Result:" + httpResponse.StatusCode + ";");
```

Then on first payment you'lll get an error

```
>curl -u "sk_test_51KiFsQIZBabXT9vC1SZAcFMJpgdBHFHa1rMBjaMntI4gGEAGciPFkrERfISvM37sS1SNHcJThaRwjgwLh0bW8u9n00mjcVcPFN:" --data "amount=1099&currency=eur&payment_method_data[type]=card&payment_method_data[card][number]=4242424242424242&payment_method_data[card][exp_month]=4&payment_method_data[card][exp_year]=24&payment_method_data[card][cvc]=242&payment_method_options[card][moto]=true&confirm=true" https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

then following this url [https://silkstartsupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000538368-Stripe-Error-Sending-credit-card-numbers-directly-to-the-Stripe-API-is-generally-unsafe-#:~:text=As%20of%20October%202017%2C%20Stripe,who%20wanted%20to%20continue%20processing](https://silkstartsupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000538368-Stripe-Error-Sending-credit-card-numbers-directly-to-the-Stripe-API-is-generally-unsafe-#:%7E:text=As%20of%20October%202017%2C%20Stripe,who%20wanted%20to%20continue%20processing)

you must go to

https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/integration

click advanced options and set the toogle option to allow data from card directly

and done.

Reemerb that you first need to ask manually8 stripe to give you enable the MOTO option

Comment: still bad request with .net. CLIL cmd works find using: curl -u "sk_test_yurkey" --data "amount=1099&currency=eur&payment_method_data[type]=card&payment_method_data[card][number]=4242424242424242&payment_method_data[card][exp_month]=4&payment_method_data[card][exp_year]=24&payment_method_data[card][cvc]=242&payment_method_options[card][moto]=true&confirm=true" https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents

Answer (score 0):

finally working with below code:

```
var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents";
var httpRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer sk_test_YOUR KEY";
var data = "amount=1099&currency=eur&payment_method_data[type]=card&payment_method_data[card][number]=4242424242424242&payment_method_data[card][exp_month]=4&payment_method_data[card][exp_year]=24&payment_method_data[card][cvc]=242&payment_method_options[card][moto]=true&confirm=true";
using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream())) { streamWriter.Write(data); }
var httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) { var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); }
Response.Write("Resultado:" + httpResponse.StatusCode + ";");
```